# All REQUIRES missing in the CMakeLists.txt

Tags: linker, esp-idf, cmakelists-options

I'm updating a project with ESP-IDF from version 3.0.9 to 4.3 release, and I'm fixing legacy code to have a compiling version.

I installed the VS Code pluign v1.1.0, and compiled example project without  problems.

My current CMakeList is something like

```
idf_component_register(INCLUDE_DIRS "." "addrs" "button" "certs"
                       SRC_DIRS  "." "addrs" "button" "certs"
                       EMBED_TXTFILES "certs/ca.crt"
                       EMBED_FILES "web/bin/style.css.min.gz")
```

Now I'm fixing the code and I'm facing a linking problem, for example

> undefined reference to `mbedtls_md5_starts'

The compilation seems to proceed further if I add the row

```
REQUIRES "mbedtls"
```

but suddenly I face problems with others (nvs_flash, mdns, mqtt_client, ...)

With the old make, I didn't have this kind of problem (no REQUIRES equivalent needed), so I'm thinking I should setup something better. Should I REQUIRES all packages, or is there something to setup to solve the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that you don't need to explicitly declare all your dependencies - according to the [ESP IDF build system documentation](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/build-system.html#optional-project-variables) it tries to include all components by default.

Regardless, I use `REQUIRES` in my project to make them explicit (and hopefully reduce compilation time). The doc says that when you go that way, you have to follow it to the end, otherwise it won't even include the relevant header files, not to mention the code for unlisted components.

The good news is that I'm pretty sure you only need to list the highest level components like `REQUIRES "nvs_flash" "mdns" "esp_http_client"` which should in turn pull in their lower level dependencies like `mbedtls`. As an example, this is in my CMakeLists:

```
...
    REQUIRES
        "spi_flash"
        "nvs_flash"
        "gcp_iot_sdk"
        "wpa_supplicant"# This is already required by other components, but we
                        # explicitly require it for an include path to endian.h
        "app_update"    # OTA
        "esp_https_ota" # HTTPS OTA
        "esp_https_server"
        "httpd_basic_auth"
        "mdns"
        "json"
        "wear_levelling"# Wear levelling library for FAT file system
        "fatfs"         # File system
...
```